# Is there a desktop wallpaper with the elementary os logo?

Tags: wallpaper

I wonder why there is no wallpaper available with the
**elementary os logo**

Answer (score 0):

A quick search online will show a few dozen options spread across a number of sites, but the wallpapers that are included in Elementary OS are generally chosen to inspire people rather than self-promote.

[image: Google Image Search Result]

That said, if this is something that you feel strongly about, you are more than welcome to create some backgrounds and build a site that promotes them. With a little backing from the eOS community, some many even be chosen for future releases of the operating system